# How to extract strings before the first delimiter, between the first and last delimiter and after the last delimiter in python3?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a script that returns strings of the form -

```
   http-STYPE-CONNECT-new/mydir/20200215_14-30-01/http/PAY_STYPE-CONNECT-new/ "Check for atleast one http 200": Expression '($1=="r" && $13==200)' matched 0 time(s), which is below specified min of 1
   http-PARALLEL-new/mydir/20200215_14-30-01/http/PAY_PARALLEL-new/ "Check for atleast one http 200": Expression '($1=="r" && $13==200)' matched 0 time(s), which is below specified min of 1
   http-STYPE-new/mydir/20200215_14-30-01/http/PAY_STYPE-new/ "Check for atleast one http 200": Expression '($1=="r" && $13==200)' matched 0 time(s), which is below specified min of 1
   http-STYPE-CONNECT-0RTT-new/mydir/20200215_14-30-01/http/PAY_STYPE-CONNECT-0RTT-new/ "Check for atleast one http 200": Expression '($1=="r" && $13==200)' matched 0 time(s), which is below specified min of 1
```

I would like to split (or apply regex) each string in such a way that everything *before* the first '/' is stored into variable `test_name`, everything *between* the first '/' and last '/' **of the path** is stored in variable `path` and everything after the last '/' **of the path** is stored in the variable `failure_reason`.

Example:

`test_name = http-STYPE-CONNECT-new`

`path = /mydir/20200215_14-30-01/http/PAY_STYPE-CONNECT-new/`

`failure_reason = "Check for atleast one http 200": Expression '($1=="r" && $13==200)' matched 0 time(s), which is below specified min of 1`

There are two other possibilities that could make the parsing complex -

1. There could be a `\n` anywhere between the string. For example: after the last '/' of the path.
2. There can be a '/' in the string that could appear after the last '/' of the path.

I simply tried using the `split('/'), join(), strip()` functions in python3, but couldn't really manage to get what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: It looks like there are matching pre and post fix strings. e.g. STYPE-CONNECT-new. Could you extract the prefix and use that to find the postfix as a terminator?

Comment: @gph: Thank you for the hint. The strings (pre) may be different. E.g h2-TYPE1-NA-old.

Comment: Looks like you are looking to create a regex, but do not know where to get started. Please check [Reference - What does this regex mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618) resource, it has plenty  of hints. Also, refer to [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2759417/3832970) post for some basic regex info. Once you get some expression ready and still have issues with the solution, please edit the question with the latest details and we'll be glad to help you fix the problem.